# Infowindow google maps api numbers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to display a date format in  google maps api infowindow on click of a marker.

I am not able to do it. Is this a bug that only strings are to be displayed on click of a marker.

```
content = "19/11/2015"

   infowindow.setContent(content);
```

Comment: "19/11/2015" is a string.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Info windows</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru
  });

    var contentString ="19/11/2015"
    //this also works
    //  '<div>19/11/2015</div>' 
    //and this
    //  var date=new Date();
    //  var contentString =date.getDay()+'/'+date.getMonth()+'/'+date.getFullYear();

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
  });
  marker.addListener('click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```